# Getting time from DB as UTC+9:00- Django

Tags: django

This is my Django test code.

```
TODAY=timezone.localtime()
AFTER_6MONTH = datetime.timedelta(days=180)

class TestView_Time(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        TimeSchedule.objects.create(start_date=TODAY,
                                     end_date=TODAY+AFTER_6MONTH,
                                     round_number=1,
                                     id=1)
    def test_time_setting(self):
        print(timezone.localtime(RoundSchedule.objects.get(id=1).start_date))
        print(RoundSchedule.objects.get(id=1).end_date)
```

And this is Output.

```
2021-07-29 14:31:38.605785+09:00
2021-08-28 05:31:38.605785+00:00
```

I want to make second Output line as First line. not using local time function. How can I change default setting??

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ko-kr'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Post your country capital city name too

Answer (score 0):

You need to change TIME_ZONE = 'YOUR COUNTRY TIME ZONE'
Assuming you are from Korea

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'
```

Comment: what if I've already did that?? I revised my question

Comment: try using django timezone instead of python

Comment: am I not using Django timezone??

Comment: from django.utils import timezone
I used this statement